# I am not able to find an exact match for child elements using XPATH

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, automation

My requirement is to send a string into the webdriver and match the string with the label for the radio button.

```
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_190');render_selected_term('190','1','275467','AQCB Number')" value="190" name="radio_190"/>
<input type="radio" onclick="Element.show('indicator_radio_term_179');render_selected_term('179','1','275467','AQCB Number (iLink)')" value="179" name="radio_179"/>
```

The above is the structure of two radio buttons with names "`AQCB Number`" and "`AQCB Number (iLink)`". So when I hand over the string "AQCB Number" I then want to find the Radio Button with that exact same text.

When i use     `//input[contains(@onclick,'AQCB Number')]`       to fetch the xpath with the label, i get both the results which is throwing an exception. Is there a way where i can find an exact match and still use contains? "`AQCB Number`" and "`AQCB Number (iLink)`" are the labels of the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Include the single quote too:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@onclick, \"'AQCB Number'\")]"));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@onclick, '\'AQCB Number\'')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question is not specifically about how to distinguish your AQCB-entries but how you can match the exact child you want

I suggest using the value or name attribute to get the match **in a more readable way**:

first **by name**:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("radio_190"));
```

or **by value**:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = '190']"));
```

#### UPDATE

After clarification from the OP, what his actual requirement is, then the solution of @peetya is of course correct:

You just need to also use the quotation marks which are found in the js code of the onclick event:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@onclick, '\'AQCB Number\'')]"));
```

*To go further, if you are handing over a String "radioButtonName" you should do something like this then:*

```
String searchString = "'" + radioButtonName + "'";

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@onclick, '" + searchString + "')]"));
```

Comment: My requirement is to send a string into the webdriver and match the string with the label for the radio button. The value is not in series and is not helping me in any way.

Comment: then it is of course best to put this essential information into your question!